# Unable to manually set the intervals for Y axis

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I have a HTML5 column chart in my jasper report. I need to configure the y axis and be able to set the intervals manually

I have used,

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.count" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval" value="2"/>
```

It has no effect on the chart

The source code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="customizechart" pageWidth="1000" pageHeight="1000" columnWidth="960" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="23a00417-b19d-4f98-aa59-dc6422d51386">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.count" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval" value="2"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select * from some_table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AppliedQuantity" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="959" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="960" height="500" uuid="774dd6b9-b5b9-4d3c-b518-6f7c7ca40043"/>
                <hc:chart xmlns:hc="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts http://jaspersoft.com/schema/highcharts.xsd" type="Column">
                    <hc:chartSetting name="default">
                        <hc:chartProperty name="chart.zoomType">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA["xy"]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="credits.enabled">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[false]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="credits.href">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="credits.text">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="title.text">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                        <hc:chartProperty name="yAxis.title.text">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[""]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>
                    </hc:chartSetting>
                    <multiAxisData>
                        <multiAxisDataset/>
                        <dataAxis axis="Rows">
                            <axisLevel name="Name">
                                <labelExpression><![CDATA["Level Label expression"]]></labelExpression>
                                <axisLevelBucket class="java.lang.String">
                                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></bucketExpression>
                                </axisLevelBucket>
                            </axisLevel>
                        </dataAxis>
                        <dataAxis axis="Columns"/>
                        <multiAxisMeasure name="Measure1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Nothing">
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA["f"]]></labelExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{AppliedQuantity}]]></valueExpression>
                        </multiAxisMeasure>
                    </multiAxisData>
                    <hc:series name="Measure1"/>
                </hc:chart>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

`net.sf.jasperreports.chart.*` properties apply to the charts built into the community/open source JasperReports library (which are based on JFreeChart).

For HTML5 charts - part of JasperReports Professional - what you have to do is set the `yAxis.tickInterval` property in the chart:

```
<hc:chartProperty name="yAxis.tickInterval">
    <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[500]]></hc:propertyExpression>
</hc:chartProperty>
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I am using yAxis.min = 0 , yAxis.max = 5 , yAxis.allowDecimal = true. I am unable to set the interval to 0.5. What is the syntax for yAxistickInterval for 0.5 interval?

Comment: I found it. Just adding yAxis.tickInterval = 0.5 did not work. I had to go the source code and add <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[new Float(0.5)]]></hc:propertyExpression></hc:chartProperty>. Then, it worked !